# MS SQL тормозит база при апдейте

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Нужно построить запрос на апдейт таблицы.

Проблема в том, что на время выполнения этого запроса лочатся (или просто тормозят) все остальные запросы к использующимся таблицам.

Как это можно обойти и с какими последствиями?

```sql
update tab1 set col = `dummy`
```

Допустим, этот запрос выполняется 5 минут. Все эти 5 минут обращения к tab1 выпадают по таймауту.

Comment: Все телепаты, ясновидящие и гадалки в отпуске

Comment: видимо потому, что у Вас MyISAM, а в этом случае блочится вся таблица при insert'ах.

Comment: @KoVadim в случае MySQL можно было бы посоветовать использовать InnoDB вместо MyISAM. А что с MS SQL?

Comment: если таблица большая, то побоку, какая база данных - обновить столбец в всей таблице - очень затратно и долго.

что же делать с mssql (который Вы как верный майкрософтовец назвали просто sql)? - забыть и выбросить!

Но есть обходной путь. Можно обновлять записи пачками. Поделить по id на логические группы и обновлять. Это костыль, но ... если сильно надо.

Comment: Вы точно хотите всякий раз обновлять **все записи** таблицы? Обычно в UPDATE присутствует условие WHERE.

Comment: @KoVadim на вопросе стоит метка sql-server, которая и на ruSO, и на enSO означает именно ms sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас обычный SQL Server (не Azure) то по умолчанию у вас уровень изоляций READ COMMITTED. Как при этом выполняется ваш апдейт:

1. Устанавливается IU - intent update lock на таблицу. Он означает что ваш процесс собрался найти в этой таблице строки, которые надо обновить.
2. Начинают перебираться строки в поиске тех, которые надо обновить. Перед тем, как проверить, стоит ли обновлять строку, на нее ставится U lock.
3. Как только первая строка для обновления найдена - устанавливается IX lock на таблицу. Ваш процесс реально собрался обновлять данные.
4. На конкретную строку устанавливается X lock.
5. установка U и X локов продолжается для всех строк, что приводит к установке X-локов на каждую обновленную строку.

Таким образом, от момента когда найдена хотя бы одна запись для обновления и до завершения транзакции (до конца апдейта) на всех обновляемых строках висят X-локи.

Одновременно с этим выполняется SELECT:

1. На таблицу устанавливается IS lock - intent shared
2. На все выбираемые строки устанавливаются S lock.

Проблема в том, что по [правиалам совместимости локов](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172925(v=sql.110).aspx) S lock нельзя поставить на строчку, на которой уже стоит X lock. Собственно, это и есть суть уровня изоляций READ COMMITTED - X lock означает что данные изменены другим процессом, но изменения еще не вкоммитаны - и из-за этого их нельзя прочитать.

Таким образом, если у вас много обновляемых данных (вся таблица, без where) или процесс поиска обновляемых данных занимает много времени (where есть, но мимо индекса/статистики/сложное - стоит посмотреть план!) - то на время обновления все висит, тормозит и падает по таймауту.

Обойти это досадное ограничение можно включением snapshot isolation и заменой READ COMMITTED на READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT.

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

В READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT SELECT будет выбирать данные из своей собственной копии, и не будет ставить S locks на строки. Cоответственно, не будет натыкаться при установке S locks на чужие X locks и не будет их ждать.

На SQL Azure READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT включен по умолчанию, и его нельзя выключить.

P.S. это решит проблему с блокировками и таймаутами, но не с тормозами. Тормоза скорее всего вызваны активной работой с диском - изменения пишутся в transaction log. Обойти это можно добавив памяти (тогда все остальные запросы будут читать данные их кэша), или поставив SSD (и все равно докинуть памяти, ее никогда не бывает много).

Answer (score 0):

```
while exists(select 1 from tab1 where col != 'dummy')
begin
    update top(1000) tab1
    set col = 'dummy'
    where col != dummy
end
```